# Highcharts Gauge Spacing

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Have two things i am trying to achieve. The first is how do i reduce the space underneath the gauge. When i reduce the size of the height it makes the gauge smaller as well. I wish to keep the gauge the same size and just reduce the space underneath ?

Secondly, how would you go about moving the L1,L2, and L3 to be in the middle vertically (so that they are more lined up).

```
    <div style="height: 20px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div id="buz1" style="text-align:center;">
        <div id="containerSide" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto; display:inline-block;"><div   style="font-size: 24px;  vertical-align: middle; color:white">L1</div></div>
        <div id="container-speed6" style="width: 400px; height:  200px; margin: 0 auto; display:inline-block;"></div>            
        <div id="container-speed7" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; display:inline-block;"></div>
        <div id="container-speed8" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; display:inline-block;"></div>
    </div>         
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You can control size / position of gauges by [pane.size](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.size) and [center](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#pane.center)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Chart with `solidgause` and to reduce padding use negative numbers, as follows:

```
chart: {
   type: 'solidgauge',
   spacingBottom: -90,
   spacingTop: -50
},
```

Result:

[image]